# Obtain page used to redirect

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am wondering how to get the page used to redirect. For example, the website [sartori-utensili.myshopify.com](http://sartori-utensili.myshopify.com), when entering this domain name into browser, it will jump to https://utensili.store/. But how can we obtain the page "sartori-utensili.myshopify.com"? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally if a page redirected then there was no original page.

If `example.com` redirects to `somesite.com` then `example.com` returned a code of, probably, 301 along with the URL for `somesite.com` and that was the entire response. There was no HTML, just a response code of 301 and an HTTP response header telling the browser where to navigate to.

I used [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to hit the URL you specified and turned off auto-redirect. I got the following content:

```
<html>
  <body>You are being 
    <a href="https://utensili.store/">redirected</a>.
  </body>
</html>
```

Along with the headers:

```
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Language →it
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Date →Sun, 14 Jan 2018 21:44:50 GMT
Location →https://utensili.store/
P3P →CP="NOI DSP COR NID ADMa OPTa OUR NOR"
Server →nginx
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-Dc →chi2,ash
X-Download-Options →noopen
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies →none
X-Request-ID →9840f718-5284-4d3f-a19d-a81aaf3a4cd5
X-ShardId →29
X-ShopId →8266121
X-Sorting-Hat-PodId →29
X-Sorting-Hat-PodId-Cached →0
X-Sorting-Hat-Section →pod
X-Sorting-Hat-ShopId →8266121
X-Sorting-Hat-ShopId-Cached →0
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block; report=/xss-report?source%5Baction%5D=index&source%5Bapp%5D=Shopify&source%5Bcontroller%5D=storefront_section%2Fshop&source%5Bsection%5D=storefront&source%5Buuid%5D=9840f718-5284-4d3f-a19d-a81aaf3a4cd5
```

Comment: Apart from it being a 301, the presumptions are corrrect.  301 means permanent, no need to retry the old address, 302 is temporary.

Comment: I corrected from 302 to 301 once I hit it with postman and saw the result

Comment: It is possible for the original address to return a page, which when loaded, loads another address, through eg. javascript or a meta-tag refresh.  They might use that if they want to make it clear there is a new address, giving you the time to read a message.

Comment: Yes, but using something like postman (Link in my answer) will allow you to disable meta refresh, javascript and 301/302 response codes.

Comment: I agree, I just meant to say that there could have been a page.

Comment: I am a new guy in web. Thanks for your idea~

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you want to get from the redirecting page. If the page redirects, then the author for some reason doesn't want you to see it. You can look into it's code however, using some feature like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)